# Small amount of oil in coolant

Tags: honda, accord, oil-in-coolant

My car is honda accord 2015 v6
I noticed that my coolant have some oil in it but it’s not creamy or thick, its just coolant water but with extra viscosity, my local mechanic said “this is the coolant water and oil is not mixed with it, and its normal” I checked the engine oil and its good as any oil, the color is good and no signs of water.
I remember that in april i had a heating problem but the car didn’t overheat to the max  ,the problem was with the cooling fans and i fixed it.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0):

If this were a minimal amount of water in the oil, I'd say there's no issue. Considering it's the other way around, there certainly could be an issue. The reason I say this is because due to the combustion process, there will always be a small amount of water in the oil, which is then usually evaporated once the oil is heated up. On the other hand, there's no real way for oil to get into the water unless there is a leak somewhere. The only other way for oil to get in there is if someone put it in there by mistake.

My suggestion to you is to get the coolant flushed and replaced. If it comes back or gets work, then you know there's a real issue. If it doesn't come back, or if it's there but lighter than it was before (oil is tough to clean out without several flushes), there's probably no issue and chalk it up to "one of those weird things".